# The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>" at Blogger

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, blogger

I can't use this code:

```
<input id="drop" type="checkbox">
```

And if I do like `<input id="drop" type="checkbox"></input>` or `<input>id="drop" type="checkbox"</input>`, I still can't. How can I use this drop down at [Blogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29)?

```html
<div class="drop-down-menu">
    <nav>
        <label class="toggle" for="drop">Menu <span>&#9776;</span></label>
        <input id="drop" type="checkbox">

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li>
                <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Category <span>&#9776;</span></label>
                <a href="#">Category</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

You can see the full dropdown menu here: https://codepen.io/cadangan37/pen/mWJzoq

Comment: What about `<input id="drop" type="checkbox" />`?

Comment: Why can't you? What seems to go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try `<input id="foo" type="checkbox" />`.

Edit: just saw j08961 wrote the same in comments before me, apologies.

Comment: this can, but i cant open at mobile menu.

Comment: That's a very different problem and you should open another question for this secondary problem.

Answer (score 0):

It missed `<input id="drop" type="checkbox"/>`.

Comment: What do you mean by "missed"?`Can you elaborate? Three is a already similar one: `<input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>`